# How to remove the NA from summary of glm?

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I made a regression mode:

```
LogitModel<- glm(y~TimeBetweenStartRegAndEndReg+Age_wn+Train_Data[,1]+Train_Data[,2]+Train_Data[,3]+Train_Data[,4]
            +Train_Data[,5]+Train_Data[,6]+Train_Data[,7]+Train_Data[,8]+Train_Data[,9]
            +Train_Data[,10]+Train_Data[,11]+Train_Data[,12]+Train_Data[,13]+Train_Data[,14]
            +Train_Data[,15]+Train_Data[,16]+Train_Data[,17]+Train_Data[,18]+Train_Data[,19]
            +Train_Data[,20]+Train_Data[,21]+Train_Data[,22]+Train_Data[,23]+Train_Data[,24]
            +Train_Data[,25]+Train_Data[,26]
             ,family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

all the variables are factor except TimeBetweenStartRegAndEndReg and Age_wn.

the output *summary(LogitModel)* is not understood for me.
there are NA for some variables. what it means that the coefficiant is NA?

And the most important how to remove them NA from the summary?

And another thing how can i print a model just with the significant coefficiant ?

Comment: Sorry for this off-center comment, but I would be surprised if the language you are using (which is what language?) didn't have a simpler syntax for summing an array of numbers.

Comment: @rschwieb what? i don't understand you. The script is written in R.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. Doesn't sum(TrainData[,:]) compute that long sum you typed out? I can't test it and my R is a little rusty.

Comment: Additional threads concerned with the appearance of `NA` in regression summaries can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+NA).  @rschwieb You are right to suggest there must be a simpler expression, but `sum` won't do it: the expression in the model is a *formula*, not an arithmetic summation.  `y ~ TimeBetweenStartRegAndEndReg + Age_wn + Train_Data[, 1:26]` should work fine.